# Does boost program_options support off-switches (e.g. --no-myswitch or -s=no)

Tags: c++, boost-program-options, command-line-arguments

When I define a boolean switch for my program, say,

```
("foo,f", "frobnicate")
```

I want to be able to say

```
myprogram --foo
myprogram --no-foo
myprogram --foo=no
```

or at the very least, the first and one of the second or the third. Does program_options support this somehow? Or do I have to 'manually' define these switches?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define them yourself.

The library tells you what options have been given on the command line, and then it's up to you to map those options to features/flags/whatever. As such, it doesn't tell you whether features/flags/whatever are "on" or "off"; that's the remit of your handling code.

Comment: That wasn't what I'm asking. I was asking what the library can be made to take in from the command line for a switch.

Comment: @ein You said _"Or do I have to 'manually' define these switches?"_. The answer is yes. As I said.

Comment: That's the first sentence. The second sentence is the less-relevant part.

Comment: @ein What? How can it be "the first sentence" when it's the final sentence? I honestly have no idea what you're trying to get at.